# PHP objecture structure chainability

Tags: php

I am trying to build a huge object structure that depends on hundreds of queries. To make it performant i did the following approach:

1. Each query result object is build into an object. For example a result set from table "apples" is build into an apple object. An orange result is build into an orange object.
2. Each object is saved in the registry, where the registry is a global array with functions like isExistent($type, $id), add($type, $obj) and get($type, $id). I want to store each object from point 1 once here to access it later without needing to call another query for the object (tons of objects are needed several times at different places).
3. I want objects to be chained together so i can do something like $tree->getFruits()->getApple()->getPlace()->getName(). I also want objects in my hierarchy to be linked in both directions for later use.

Why do i need this? For example the "apple" object with id 3 will be used once when the $tree object is instantiated, once when the $vitamins object is created, etc. I don't want to sent another query() each time to the database this object is needed. So i check something like:

```
Registry::isExistent("APPLE", $id)
```

and then get it from the Registry if it is there, and otherwise call it from db and then additionally add it to registry.

Problem: I am getting infinite loops for obvious reasons, which i could easily fix, but i don't know what's the best approach here.

Actual Code (not example stuff like apples and oranges from above):

```
$mask = new Mask($row["maskId"], $row["maskName"]);
foreach (Fields::getFieldsFor($mask->getId()) as $field) {
    $mask->addField($field);
}
Registry::add("MASK", $mask);
```

and the getter for a field of a mask:

```
$mask = Registry::receive("MASK", $row["maskId"]);
        $category = Registry::receive("FIELDTYPE", $row["fieldCategory"]);
$field = new Field($row["fieldId"], $category, $row["fieldQuestion"],
                $row["fieldDescription"], $row["fieldPosition"], null, null, null, $mask);
            Registry::add("FIELD", $field);
```

This will produce an infinite loop. A mask consists of several fields. When building the $mask object i want to have each field linked in the $mask array. When building each $field object i want to parent $mask linked to it. This will obviously fail because i only add to registry, AFTER they are done building which will obviously fail because before that they will already have a look at the registry.

There are 2 solutions i can think of:

1. Throw away my chainability and simply store the linked ids in my objects. So instead of storing a reference to the parent mask object in each field i would simply store the id and later retreive the actual object from the registry. This would be the easiest fix, but would throw away the chainability.
2. Split up the primitive object instantiation and the complex attributes. Just add the primitives via the constructor and add the complex like the actual $mask object to each field after the constructor AND after the Registry::add() via a setter.

What would be best to do here? Is something wrong in my general approach?

My goal simply is to build an easy to work with object structure (will be hundreds of objects) and to reduce redundant queries(). This really needs to be fast. I also only want each different object once and then linked accordingly in the complex object structure.

Thanks and sorry for a long description.

Comment: have you considered using laravel eloquent for this? http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent

Comment: @MichaelDibbets: Didn't know about eloquent. Problem with that and any other framework now is, that i put a lot of work into my approach and actually want to use it now. So i would rather use my own solution than a finished framework. Which just leads to the question what needs to be fixed at my approach

Comment: Okay, I can get that because of the perception of wasted time. But looking at what you wrote, from the viewpoint of maintainabilty and future updates I strongly suggest you consider restarting in eloquent. It does what you want and more, much more. You are basically reinventing a wheel that has been inventend multiple times. But it's your choice.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets Sure, but as a informatics student i will have learned a lot from doing it myself. Next project i would use something like eloquent now that i know of it. It would be just a lot of wasted time (few thousand lines of code) to replace the current controllers and logic with eloquent. Just what would be best to fix my "lite-version" of eloquent?

Comment: Try to look into collections libaries. You can also make a semi table like structure. you have one array which is numerical, 0 > whatever length. then you have other associative arrays that reference(& operator) the value in the numerical array. And you use those in your seek functions. You still have the issues with multiple duplicate keys to resolve... I really would use eloquent or a similar libary.

Answer (score 0):

well, i've done something similar for one project few years ago using [PHP Magic Method __get()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get). What i've done actually is storing the Getter Object inside a variable called `Registry.get`; something like: `$this->get = new GetterObject($this);`. Now, notice that i passed the `Registry` as a variable to my `GetterObject`, you might ask "why?" simply this is:

## How it Works

1. The `GetterObject` gets initialized with the `Registry` as a variable (unless `Registery` as a global absolute object then no need for this!).
2. You "get" a ORM-object using something like `Registery::get->fruits;`.
3. The `GetterObject` will check the `Registry` array of objects to find `fruits` ORM-object.
4. The `GetterObject` will return a new instance of itself with some additional variables defining at which step you are; something like `$this->path = "/fruits/";`.
5. Now, when you "get" the second object, say, `Registery::get->fruits->apples;`, the `GetterObject` will simple check which was the last `$this->path` piece, on which it will depend to find the child element. Note that this step depends highly on how you structured your own ORM-objects array.
6. The `GetterObject` will repeat steps 4, and 5 until you end up with the object of desire and do something like `->return_values();` which is a defined function that returns the actual ORM-object you are looking for, not the `GetterObject` you were using to navigate through your ORM-objects.

As a small note again, this might not be the best practice for all the `Registry`-based platforms, so, make sure you really need something this complicated before doing so. Otherwise, a simple `__get()` definition might all what you need. Best of Luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your Registry approach sounds a lot more complicated than my simple approach. You are practially doing something ORM light, while i just store stuff to prevent redundant queries. And yes, i need that because actually a $field object can be used 100 times at the whole webproject in a single load and i need to prevent those 99 redundant calls. I guess from the two given answers, i will just go with my 1st idea: throw away the real chainability and just store the simple Ids which i can later use to get the real objects from the registry.

Comment: Well, my approach was my only option when I worked on my project as I had back then path-like chaining without knowing what items I'm dealing with as they were being added programmatically. Good luck with your approach!